# Desktop mirroring using AirServer 7 on Mac and AirParrot 3 on Windows 10 doesn't work — any way to fix that?

Tags: macos, windows, airplay, monterey, mirroring

I'm using AirServer 7.2.7 on my MacBook Pro (Late 2016, macOS Monterey 12.1) and trying to send my Windows desktop (Windows 10) using AirParrot 3. Both computers are connected to the same WiFi-network. I'm getting "Access requested" pop-up on my Mac an click on "Allow", but nothing happens after that. Is there a way to fix that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Official **AirParrot** support answer:

> Unfortunately, we are not able to support AirServer. Sorry about that!
> You may want to test out the free trial version of Reflector for this.

And here is the **AirServer** support answer:

> Unfortunately, Miracast mirroring, like used in Windows 10 and some Android devices, is currently only available in AirServer Connect 4K UHD, AirServer Universal, and AirServer for Windows 10 Desktop Edition.
>
> Windows and Android Operating Systems, are using Intel's Wi-Fi Direct
> technology for peer to peer discovery and connections while the Mac
> uses Apple's Wireless Direct Link for peer to peer discovery and
> connections.
>
> Currently, Mac computers from Apple do not have the hardware or
> drivers required to use Wi-Fi Direct. If the hardware and drivers
> installed on Apple's Mac computers support the Wi-Fi Direct
> Technology, we will go ahead and add the Miracast feature to AirServer
> for Mac.